# Really stuck with adding delete and add rows to my user table on my admin page

Tags: php, mysql, admin, edit, sql-delete

AdminAccount.php

```
<?php

ob_start();
include 'connection.php';
$ses = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

echo "<h3> User Account Information </h3>";

if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"] )) {

    print "<table border=1 cellpadding='5' width = 100px height = 100px align='middle'>";

    print "<th>username</ th>";

    print "<th>Password</ th>";

    print "<th>email</ th>";

    print "<th>edit information</ th>";

    print "<th>delete information</ th>";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Register";


    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo " <tr>";

        echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";

        echo " <form action= InfoActions.php  method= 'post'>
        <td><input type= 'submit' name = 'type' value= 'Edit'/></td>
        <td><input type= 'submit' name = 'type' value= 'Delete'/></td>";

        echo "</tr>";
//echo "<td><a href='EditInfo.php?id=" . $row['user_id'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";

    }
    echo "</table>";
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $query = ("UPDATE Register SET username = '$username' , password = '$password' , email = '$email' WHERE user_id='$ses'");


$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);


header('location:ProtectedPage.php');   
//Temporarily echo $query for debugging purposes    

//run $query
}
```

InfoActions.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include 'connection.php';
    $ses = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
        $urls = array(
            'Edit Information' => 'EditInfo.php',
            'Delete' => 'DeleteInfo.php'
        );
        $url = $urls[$_POST['type']];
    }

    ?>
```

I'll let you know now I copied the InfoActions.php code and changed it a bit but don't fully understand the `(isset($_POST['type']), $url and $url = $urls[$_POST['type']];` bit!

EditInfo.php

```
    <form method="post" action="AdminAccount.php">
            <lable for ="Username" > Username: </lable> </br>
            <input type="text" name="username" value=''/> </br>

            <lable for ="Password" > Password: </lable> </br>
            <input type="password" name="password" /> </br>

            <lable for ="Email" > Email: </lable> </br>
            <input type="email" name="email" /> </br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
            <input type="reset"  value="clear" />
        </form>
```

DeleteInfo.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $ses = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM Register WHERE user_id=$user_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    ?>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Your adminaccount file doesn't have `session_start();` is it in fact in there and you didn't include it in your question?

Comment: Plus you're also mixing MySQL APIs, you can't do that. I.e.: `mysql_query` and `mysqli_*` functions. Change `$result = mysql_query($query);` to `$result = mysqli_query($query);`

Comment: it doesnt need a session_start because this file is included within my AdminAccount.php where it contains a session_start didnt include that page because it is irrelevant to question, i'll correct the mysqli now thanks Fred, Nick sorry but the question is pretty simple what im asking

Comment: even with corrected mysqli when im clicking on the delete and edit buttons rather than being redirected to correct page or having the command completed i just get a white screen displayed

Comment: You commented out `echo "<td><a href='EditInfo.php?id=" . $row['user_id'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";` Does hard coding and running it work? @user3546129

Comment: its meant to be commented out as that bit works for just my editinfo.php but im trying to implement a form which allows both edit and delete to work with forms rather than a hyperlink to a form.

Comment: You're best to use a hidden element then. I.e.: `echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $row['user_id'] . '">';` or `echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . '">';` @user3546129

Comment: I've seen this hidden element but never used it as im not sure what it does and i don't really like using code i don't understand.

Comment: You won't have a choice. That's how it's done when querying your DB through a loop. You need to fetch your data first in order to be able to alter it in any way. There's no better time to start and learn, than the present ;-)

Comment: any chance you could edit my code and show me how its done or how it looks cause honestly mate im about to break something I've been sat in uni staring at my computer for about 4 hours trying so many different ways to do this

Comment: Inside your loop where you have `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` place this below that 
`$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];` then just under `<td><input type= 'submit' name = 'type' value= 'Edit'/></td>` put 
`<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">` I can't edit your code. You need to try it yourself. There's no better way to learn, really.

Comment: As an added tool, use `var_dump();` on any variable if you're having a hard time. I.e.: `var_dump($_SESSION['user_id];` etc.

Comment: Plus, you're going to have to put quotes around `<form action= InfoActions.php  method= 'post'>` as in `<form action= 'InfoActions.php'  method= 'post'>`

Comment: I made a slight error earlier. Do `<input type='hidden' value='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'>` instead of `<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">`

Comment: im not going to use forms mate there too much of a piss take to use within php tags